# Fetching one column values with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I need to fetch the domain id of the user who is only Active with one username that should starts with 'a-%' or 'A-%' and all other User name should be "Disabled" for system_id 349 as below image,

Expected Result:

[image]

Query I used is :

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT  p.domain_id
        FROM  ur_username u
            JOIN ur_username_person up ON u.username_id = up.username_id
            JOIN ur_person p ON up.person_id = p.person_id
            JOIN ur_system s ON u.system_id = s.system_id
          WHERE ( u.username LIKE 'A-%' OR username LIKE 'a-%') AND u.status = 'ACTIVE' AND u.system_id = 34)E
WHERE  E.domain_id IN  (SELECT  p.domain_id FROM ur_username u JOIN ur_username_person up ON u.username_id = up.username_id
    JOIN ur_person p ON up.person_id = p.person_id
  WHERE  u.system_id = 349 AND u.status = 'DISABLED')
```

For Example Pri_0911 (domain_id) is having number of usernames but he is active only the username starts with 'a-%' and all other usernames are disabled.So we need to select the domain id who are matching with this condition.

```
domain_id  | username    | status    |   system_id   |  
Pri_0911   | asdfg       | disabled  |      349      |
Pri_0911   | werdfdf     | disabled  |      349      |
Pri_0911   | zxgfg       | disabled  |      349      |
Pri_0911   | a-priya     | ACTIVE    |      349      |
```

Comment: (U.USERNAME LIKE 'A-%' or USERNAME LIKE 'a-%') in bracket. Otherwise you are saying  U.USERNAME LIKE 'A-%' OR blablabla

Comment: @MiloBellano I changed the mentioned point but still not getting the Expected Result here .Thanks

Comment: What is the output you get instead?

Comment: Also ddl of tables will be useful to understand better the joins in the query. What if one username a-% is just active and never happens it is disable? in your query you skip them I guess

Comment: Here we have domain id that may have multiple username so in that we need to select only admin account (a-%) is active and all other username is Disabled .

Comment: admin account  = username? sorry it is still confusing without ddl, what output do you get? what it is not expected?

Comment: Are you wanting to show all users for that domain, but only the admin user with an Active status, other the others should show as disbled? Some sample data (please use text, rather than images) in your tables would be very helpful to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Boneist,  Please find the below result:

Comment: You should edit your question to include the extra information

Comment: @Boneist Have edited the question with some information.Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @madhan so you want a list of the domain_id's that have at least one active user? Or are you wanting a list of the users in that domain? \*scratches head\*

Comment: @ Boneist Yes list of the domain_id's that should have only one active user (That username should starts with 'a-'). I want to display the Domain id and also the active user name. sorry for confusing the requirement

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your latest requirement correctly, doesn't the following give you what you're after?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.domain_id,
                u.username
FROM   ur_username u
       JOIN ur_username_person up ON u.username_id = up.username_id
       JOIN ur_person p ON up.person_id = p.person_id
       JOIN ur_system s ON u.system_id = s.system_id
WHERE  u.username LIKE 'A-%'
OR     u.username LIKE 'a-%';
```

Comment: @Here we have one  twist is  that the domain id is Active for some user names but , I need the domain which have only one active user that starts with 'A-%' or 'a-' for system id 349. That is why i used the two sub query . T

Comment: To save us from guessing your requirements, why not supply us with a full test case. e.g. create table statements, insert statements and the expected outcome based on this input data. Your requirements will be a lot clearer if you provide us this information.

Comment: There is no create or insert statement here I am trying to pull the Report for the Domain id who is only active in one user account (Starts with a-). All other user account must be disabled. My Query was pulled data but it is additionally pulling the domain id who are active in another user name .         There are three table involved here ur_username(Username details ) , ur_person (domain_id). ur_username_person(connecting table). This is the information I cab have to select the data.Sorry for wasting your time on this

Comment: The thing is, we can't see your database or your data. We have no idea what your tables consist of, how they're defined (primary keys, foreign keys, other constraints, indexes, etc etc). So in order to help us to be able to help you, you have to provide some sample data. We don't care about what that data is, so long as it demonstrates the issue you're trying to solve. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980467/update-duplicate-rows-only-with-a-max-function-in-sql) as an example of a decent enough question. See if you can update your question to give a more complete picture.