# Why min function returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement  to get a count of all the first offers that we extended to an employee,  it doesnt matter how many offers we extended the requirement is just capture the first offer. I have this code   written to capture that, but in cases where we extended more that one offer, its counting twice. any suggestion on what i need to tweak on my code to count only once irrespective of how many offers extedned?

```
(SELECT /*+ materialize */ 1 
FROM
(
  SELECT /*+ materialize */ 1, Rank() OVER(PARTITION BY EMP_NUM  order by CREATION_DT   asc) AS RECNUM
  FROM CTE_OFFERS ACP
  WHERE STS_NAME = 'Extended'
  AND  STEP_NAME = 'Offer'
  AND ACP.EMP_NUM  = EXT.EMP_NUM  
  AND ACP.TITLE = EXT.TITLE
 ) T2
    WHERE RECNUM=1
)  AS t1,
```

Comment: Some sample data that shows the issue would help us to help you. As it stands, I'm guessing you have two or more rows meeting those predicates which have the same creation_dt. If so, perhaps you want `row_number()` instead.

Comment: I had tried row_number and  i still get same results, the dates are not the same. AS for sample data, is there a way to attach a screenshot here?

Comment: Don't use a screen shot. Make up your own data using select from dual's and then union them all together. E.g. see the sample data at the end of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980467/update-duplicate-rows-only-with-a-max-function-in-sql). In this case, we only really need the results of your joins, so you could make up some data that shows the output of your query before you add the `rank()` function to it.

Comment: Also, why the materialize hints? I would remove those if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` function, remove `PARTITION BY EMP_NUM` and consider the following :

```
select * 
  from
  (
   with cte_offers( emp_num, creation_dt ) as
   (
    select 17, trunc(sysdate)   from dual union all
    select 18, trunc(sysdate)   from dual union all
    select 19, trunc(sysdate)+1 from dual     
   )
   select emp_num, row_number() over (order by creation_dt asc) as recnum
     from cte_offers
   )
 where recnum = 1
 order by emp_num;

EMP_NUM RECNUM
------- ------
  17       1
```

Even if the both `CREATION_DT` values are the same, it yields distinct numbers(`recnum`).

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/ZNNAOD37252)

Comment: This is a good approach but it wont give me a count. The goal is to give me  a count.

Comment: So, change `select *` into `select count(*)`?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* that there can be only one "first" offer extended to any employee,
To get all first offers extended, all you need is get distinct count of employees for which there was any offer extended:

```
select count(distinct emp_num)
from cte_offers
where sts_name = 'Extended'
and step_name = 'Offer';
```

If you need the count of first offer extended to one single employee (i.e. emp_num is given), which can be either 0 or 1 as per above assumption:

```
select count(*)
from dual
where exists (
    select 1
    from cte_offers
    where sts_name = 'Extended'
    and step_name = 'Offer'
    and emp_num = ?
)
```